# Flip Image(Mirror) in a PictureBox Control

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

First of all I am a beginner with C#.
I have a picturebox and a timer (enabled, interval = 25).
I have inserted a gif image of a bird in the picturebox.
And in the Timer event I have written,

```
bool positionBird = true;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PictureBox1.Location.X == Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width)
    {
        positionBird = false;
    }
    else if (PictureBox1.Location.X == 0)
    {
        positionBird = true;
    }

    if(positionBird)
    {
        PictureBox1.Left += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        PictureBox1.Left += -1;
    }
}
```

But what I want to achieve is, when the picture box touches the right
boundary and condition become false, I want to flip the image of bird in
the picturebox. Right now the bird is doing Michael Jackson's Moonwalk!

I tried to flip the bird (mirror the bird) using the below code.

```
else
{
    PictureBox pict = new PictureBox();
    pict = PictureBox1;
    pict.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
    pict.Left += -1;
}
```

But it looks weird. It shows the flip image and normal image both. Can
someone help me on this? As I already said I am a beginner. Some simple
code with explanation would be very helpful. Also can someone tell me
what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is this in WPF or windows forms? In WPF you can set the transform to flip it

Comment: Get the images and flip them in photoshop or any other program. Then draw them yourself

Comment: Its a gif image. i want to keep the sprite animate while flipping the image. and i want to know how to flip it using code.

Comment: You cant flip the gif because it contains images(two in your example). Open the gif and save the two images.Flip them and save them too. Now you have 4 images. Draw the first two (1 2 1 2....) in one direction and (3 4 3 4...) on the other.

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT CREATE another Picture Box. You are seeing the original picture because you have not modified the original but the newly created one.

So the modified code is follows:

```
bool positionBird = true;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PictureBox1.Location.X == Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width)
    {
        positionBird = false;
        PictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX); // picture flips only once when touches boundary
    }
    else if (PictureBox1.Location.X == 0)
    {
        positionBird = true;
        PictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX); // picture flips only once when touches boundary
    }

    if(positionBird)
    {
        PictureBox1.Left += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        PictureBox1.Left += -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wasif, Iam trying to flip the image horizontally.  pict.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX); is working fine. first it shows flipped image then normal image and it goes on till it reaches left. and the animation in gif is also not available.

Comment: first it shows flipped image then normal image, then again and again and it goes on till it reaches left. And when it reaches left the animation in the image is gone and its just showing only the first frame.

Comment: can you upload the gif here?

Comment: The picture i inserted in Picture box is a gif file with 2 frames animation. When doing the flip does it converts the image into bitmap ?? i think so, thats why i want to flip the picturebox control itself. The solution you provided works fine when using bitmap images, and i already know that. what iam trying to achieve is the same result with gif file and keep the sprite animation.